# NSNumberFormatter error from the Apple Documentation "Data Formatting Guide"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I follow the "[Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1)" from the Apple Developer website:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setFormat:@"0.00%;0.00%;-0.00%"];
NSNumber *four = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.0];
NSLog(@"%@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:four]);
```

But it throws an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNumberFormatter setFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59359b0'
```

The document was last updated on 2009, so I would not blame on that. My questions are: How do you deal with this error?

**Edited Question**

How do you specify a format on NSNumber? How do you parse a string to a number, a number to string? How do you specify the patterns that Apple pointed to us [in a document](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Number_Format_Patterns). I'm talking about iPhone programming. Thank you all!

**Edited again**

Let's generalize my question: If you take a look [at the patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Number_Format_Patterns), let's say I have a string "1 234,57 €" (the last one in the link) and I want to parse this string to a number, I need to specify the format as: "# ##0.00 ¤", but now for iPhone applications, as two people suggested, there's no setFormat: method.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setFormat:@"# ##0.00 ¤"];
NSNumber *dollars = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"1 234,57 €"];
```

How do you cope with this?

Answer (score 3):

The link you are looking at is for Mac, not iOS [NSNumberFormatterReference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNumberFormatterStyle)

try this:

```
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
```

Comment: It is the same, see here, the example I posted is still there, even though the address is different: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1

Comment: The Data Formatting guides may look the same, but if you click on the link from the iOS guide it takes you to the iOS version of the NSNumberFormatter Class Reference which is different from the Mac version. In particular, there is no `setFormat` in the iOS version. Which is why you need to make sure that you are looking at the correct versions of the documentation.

Comment: hi Abizem, could you read the comment I posted to dean as well?

Comment: +1 If you compile that code in a Mac application it will give the results given in the Apple Data Formatting Guide example; if you try it in an iOS application it will give a compiler warning `'NSNumberFormatter' may not respond to '-setFormat:'`

Comment: Hi Abizem, if you have not seen the comment below, I copied it here: "I am not talking about a special case, offcourse, I'll find the solution somehow, but I am talking in general. Take a look at the link Apple shows us: unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Number_Format_Patterns How do you specify these patterns?"

Comment: I saw the comment, but your question was about the error, not how to get a specific format.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own number formatter? And you don't specify those patterns, you use them when you create a number formatter.

Comment: Hi Abizem, I just extracted the sample code from Apple to discuss a generic problem, I already solved my simple issue. Could you take a look at the edited question again?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a setFormat: method on a NSNumberFormatter class (even though it's all over [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)!)

Try the setPositiveFormat: method instead?

---

Though looking at your example problem, this might be better :

```
NSLog(@"%f", 4.0f);
```

or, if you want to store it in a string :

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 4.0f]; // You might need to retain this!
```

Take a look at the [string formatting guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

Comment: Hi Dean, I am not talking about a special case, offcourse, I'll find the solution somehow, but I am talking in general. Take a look at the link Apple shows us: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Number_Format_Patterns How do you specify these patterns?

Comment: Ah, if you're after currency / locale stuff then stringWithFormat won't help you at all - ignore the second part of my answer! However, the first part should still work (`setPositiveFormat:`)

Comment: hi Dean, I edited my question again, let's talk about a generic one, not any specific case, I can not specify only the positiveFormat, how about negative ones?